# Hold an object, using class in python

Tags: python, class

I write a program to weave lists of floats together, for example:

```
l1 = [5.4, 4.5, 8.7]
l2 = [6.5, 7.8]
l3 = [6.7, 6.9]
```

I want to weave l1 into l2:

```
[5.4, 6.5, 4.5, 7.8, 8.7]
```

And now I want it in a class so I can hold this result and weave l3 into it:

```
[5.4, 6.7, 6.5, 6.9, 4.5, 7.8, 8.7]
```

The function I wrote two weave two lines together is:

```
def Weave_number_rows(row1,row2): #enter 2 rows of numbers as lists
    l1 = row1
    l2 = row2
    woven = sum(zip(l1, l2), ())
    print woven
```

How to hold the result with a class and weave the next line into it?

Comment: What's wrong with simple loop? How classes/objects fit in here?

Comment: to get familiar with classes I am trying to start out simple, the reason to use a class here is that I want to understand it better

Comment: What should happen when one list is several elements longer or shorter than the others? Also, if you're trying to get familiar with classes, use them only where they belong.

Comment: It seems to be wrong type of problem. I don't see how this problem helps in understanding classes. They just don't fit here.

Answer (score 3):

Your weave function drops the last element of `l2`; you need to use [`itertools.zip_longest()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) here:

```
try:
    from itertools import zip_longest
except ImportError:
    # Python 2
    from itertools import izip_longest as zip_longest

def weave_rows(row1, row2):
    return [v for v in sum(zip_longest(row1, row2), ()) if v is not None]
```

Note that you need to *return*, not print, your output. The `izip_longest()` call adds `None` placeholders, which we need to remove again from the `sum()` output after zipping.

Now you can simply weave in a 3rd list into the output of the previous two:

```
weave(weave(l1, l2), l3)
```

Demo:

```
>>> weave_rows(l1, l2)
[5.4, 6.5, 4.5, 7.8, 8.7]
>>> weave_rows(weave_rows(l1, l2), l3)
[5.4, 6.7, 6.5, 6.9, 4.5, 7.8, 8.7]
```

Answer (score 0):

Function you wrote returns `None`, as no return statement is present. Replace `print` with `return` and chain calls. You might also need `izip_longest` instead of zip for lists of nonequal size:

With izip_longest:

```
from itertools import izip_longest
def weave(l1, l2):
    return filter(None, sum(izip_longest(l1, l2), ())
```

demo

```
>>> weave(weave(l1, l2), l3)
(5.4, 6.7, 6.5, 6.9, 4.5, 7.8, 8.7)
```

Without, zip breaks on shortest argument:

```
>>> def weave_shortest(l1, l2):
        return sum(zip(l1, l2), ())
>>> weave_shortest(l3, weave_shortest(l1, l2))
(5.4, 6.7, 6.5, 6.9)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution (based on Martijn Pieters code) which avoids recursion is:

```
try:
    from itertools import zip_longest
except ImportError:
    # Python 2
    from itertools import izip_longest as zip_longest

def weave_two(row1, row2):
    return [v for v in sum(zip_longest(row1, row2, fillvalue=None), ()) if v is not None]

def weave_rows(*args):
    if len(args) < 2:
        return None
    current = weave_two(args[0], args[1])
    for i in range(2, len(args)):
        current = weave_two(current, args[i])
    return current
```

usage:

```
>>> weave_rows(l1, l2, l3)
[5.4, 6.7, 6.5, 6.9, 4.5, 7.8, 8.7]
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, as peoples comments, this seems a strange case to start using classes but something like this should work:

```
from itertools import zip_longest

class Weaver():
    def __init__(self,data):
        self.result = data

    def weave(data):
        self.result = sum(zip_longest(self.result, data),()) # or whatever version
                                                             # works best from
                                                             # the other answers

w = Weaver(l1)
w.weave(l2)
w.weave(l3)
print(w.result)
```

This creates a `Weaver` object `w` and initialises it with `l1`.  Then you weave the other lists in one by one and it stores the result internally and finally you access and print that result.